# How to make it compile?

Tags: typescript

```js
type PageParamsKeys = keyof GenericPageParams;

type GenericPageParams = {
  pathParams?: Record<string, string>;
  searchParams?: Record<string, string>;
  state?: Record<string, any>;
};

type ExactParams<T extends GenericPageParams> = keyof T extends PageParamsKeys
    ? Pick<T, PageParamsKeys>
    : never;


function usePageParams<T extends GenericPageParams>(): ExactParams<T> {
    const pathParams = {} as T["pathParams"];
    const searchParams = {} as T["searchParams"];
    const state = {} as T["state"];
    
    return {
        pathParams: pathParams,
        searchParams: searchParams,
        state: state,
    };
}
```

Whatever I try to feed to `return` it doesn't compile. I cannot understand why.
The error:

```
Type '{ pathParams: {}; searchParams: {}; state: {}; }' is not assignable to type 'ExactParamss<T>'.
```

What I want to achieve: usePageParams could accept any type which is a subset of GenericPageParams' properties, but is fully typed.

Example:

```
usePageParams<{state: { id: string }}>();
```

Comment: I could, but it basically removes typechecking, isn't it?

Comment: Yes the problem is if you use `usePageParams<{state: { id: string }}>();` (in TypeScript, which is in compile-time) how will you know what is valid to return at runtime when all type information is lost? You can't know what `usePageParams` is allowed to return at compile-time because there is no single return value that will be valid for all possible values of the generic, and there's no runtime way of knowing the generic used when compiling.

Comment: @apokryfos I've updated the question. Why doesn't  it compile now?

Comment: I believe now it should be entirely detectable at compile time, but it isn't

Comment: `T` can be e.g. `{state: { id: string }}` (or can be any of the other 2 keys, maybe more than one key) and you are returning an object with  3 keys. It's not the exact shape of T

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be exact shape, but since T which is {state: {id: string}} is constrained by GenericPageParams, its form is implicitly {state: {id: string}, pathParams: undefined, state: undefined}

Comment: yes but here you are returning `{state: {}, pathParams: undefined, searchParams: undefined }` . The shape of `state` does not match the generic.